# WebRTC video call with ARCore Android

Tags: android, webrtc, augmented-reality, arcore, webrtc-android

How to use Augmented reality Face detection functionality into webrtc video calling app?
Is this possible to use GLSurfaceview into webrtc video calling?
I am using "org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.32006" library for video calling, Now I want to use Augmented reality Face detection functionality like video calling filter functionality. So is there any way for that?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.